# Debounce multiple dispatch actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-api-middleware

I have an autocomplete component that requires results from two separate APIs. Both APIs need to be called together with a debounced period since its an autocomplete. I am using react-redux, and redux-api. This is what I have so far. Please see the Search method that I return. Problem is only one of the calls happens.

In my AutoCompleteContainer.js

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  const debounceDispatch = debounce(dispatch, 500);
  return {
    search(term) {
      return Promise.all([
        // Fix me! Only one of the calls below happens. 
        debounceDispatch(rest.actions.suggestions({ q: term })),
        debounceDispatch(rest.actions.concepts({ corpus: 'desc', term: [term] }))
      ]);
    },
    async reset() {
      await dispatch(rest.actions.suggestions.reset());
      await dispatch(rest.actions.concepts.reset());
    }
  };
};
```

Should I debounce at component level? Or can this be done here?

Comment: You should properly handle the `debounce` earlier, as in the method who is responsible for calling `search`

Comment: I debounced at the method level. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a function that dispatches both the actions, then decorate that function with `debounce`.

So something like this:

```js
const handleAutocomplete = () => {
  dispatch(rest.actions.suggestions({ q: term })),
  dispatch(rest.actions.concepts({ corpus: 'desc', term: [term] }))
}

const debounceHandleAutocomplete = debounce(handleAutocomplete,500)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have diclared and used debounce to trigger action mutile time in the following way

```
const debounce = (fn, delay = 5000) => {
    let time
    return (...args) => {
        clearTimeout(time)
        time = setTimeout(() => fn(...args), delay)
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(clientInput)) {
        debounce(fetchQuickSearchClients([ typeof clientInput === 'string' ? clientInput : clientInput.clientId ]), 3000)
    }
}, [ clientInput ])
```